# What does 助人者得人助 mean?

Tags: grammar

> 助人者得人助。

I am mostly concerned about the meaning of `者`. Its explanation is very blurry on [YellowBridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/sentsearch.php?word=%E8%80%85), and there's no article on its usage in he Chinese grammar wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

助人 = help people

助人**者** = **those who** help people

人助= people's help

**得**人助 = **get** people's help

> 者 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/591/
>
> [1] he who; those who
> [2] a particle combining with some words to form adverbials

Some example terms with 者

死 = dead; 死者 = deceased (person)

長 = elder; 長者 = elderly (person)

偽善 = hypocritical; 偽善者 = hypocrite (person)

違抗規則 = defy the rule; 違抗規則者 = those who defy the rule (person)

**Edition:**

Example for  *[2] a particle combining with some words to form adverbials-*

"兵者，凶器也" 。

兵**者**=(**definition of**) army;

凶器也 = is instrument of destruction

Comment: “……者……也” is common used as definition of something in classical chinese (文言). This two words should be translated together which means "is". e.g. 廉颇者，赵之良将也。

Answer (score 0):

I would put 助人者得到人助 somewhere under bible quotes, probably Proverbs: 'He who giveth receiveth.'

Lots of examples for 者 [here](http://ce.linedict.com/dict.html#/cnen/entry/aa2928e14b524f69bfde62d56f07f877)

电影爱好者 film freak
一群快艇爱好者 speedboat lovers
获奖者如下 and the winner/s is/are ..

Comment: 助人者得人助 sounds better. 助人者得到人助 is not that literary.

Comment: Katy Perry: "We're all chained to the rhythm." :) 新年快乐！

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. What does that sentence mean?

Comment: Katy Perry is a very sexy singer. I just meant, if you add 到 the rhythm of the phrase changes. Instead of 123, 123 we then get 123, 1234.

Answer (score 0):

助人者得人助。
助，帮助。help ,it can be verb or Noun.
者，人。person
得，得到。 obtain or get 
助人者得人助。 
This is the Chinese classical usage,
Translated into the form of modern Chinese  ：
 经常帮助别人（的人）往往也会得到（别人的）帮助。

In english: If you often help some person,you can be helped by some person.